Can not open Video file using opencv on JETSON NANO
Tried to use opencv to open a .mp4 file in NVIDIA JETSON NANO using code:
import cv2

video_path = 'bird.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Error: Cannot read frame.")
        break

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

But it does not work to preview the video file and gives error:
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261 
[ WARN:0@0.407] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2839 handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module qtdemux0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0@0.416] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1698 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.416] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1173 isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
Error: Could not open video.

The code works properly in my Windows PC to preview the video but not in JETSON NANO. Any suggestions to preview video file in using opencv on JETSON NANO?
opencv version: 4.9.0

You might want to make sure gstreamer can play your file. This often requires to install additional codecs.

Can you provide more details and resources? it would be helpful.

Your code is working on my Raspberry Pi.

assert os.path.isfile(video_path)

@toyotaSupra this code works in my Windows PC too. But not in my Jetson NANO.

You will have to install Linux on your PC.

@toyotaSupra what is the point of your suggestion?

@ChristophRackwitz somehow my code is working now without any issues. Thank you for the suggestion.
